# PostgreSQL IS NULL and length

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, string

I am trying to get all records from a table where a specific column is NULL. But I am not getting any records. On the other hand, there are many records where the length(field) is indeed 0.

```
select count(*) from article a where length(for_interest) =0;
 count 
-------
     9
(1 row)

select count(*) from article a where for_interest is NULL ;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Something about NULLs I didn't get right? More info

```
select count(*) from article AS a where for_interest is NOT NULL ;
 count 
-------
    15
(1 row)

select count(*) from article ;
 count 
-------
    15
(1 row)
```

PostgreSQL version is 9.3.2.

Adding sample data, table description etc (new sample table created with just 2 records for this)

```
test=# \d sample_article 
           Table "public.sample_article"
    Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+------------------------+-----------
 id           | integer                | 
 title        | character varying(150) | 
 for_interest | character varying(512) | 

test=# select * from sample_article where length(for_interest)=0;
 id |                              title                              | for_interest 
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
  8 | What is the Logic Behind the Most Popular Interview Questions?  | 
(1 row)

test=# select * from sample_article where for_interest IS NOT NULL;
 id |                              title                              | for_interest 
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
  7 | Auto Expo 2014: Bike Gallery                                    | Wheels
  8 | What is the Logic Behind the Most Popular Interview Questions?  | 
(2 rows)

test=# select * from sample_article where for_interest IS NULL;
 id | title | for_interest 
----+-------+--------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: your table have null value in for_interest

Comment: Its Work for me `select count(*) from article where for_interest is null` so sample data in your table and show your table structure

Comment: Edited question with the information

Comment: show table structure. did you menstion Not Null constraint in your create table

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Character types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) can hold the empty string `''`, which is **not** a `NULL` value.
The length of an empty string is 0. The length of a `NULL` value is `NULL`.
Most functions return `NULL` for `NULL` input.

```
SELECT length('');   --> 0
SELECT length(NULL); --> NULL

SELECT NULL IS NULL; --> TRUE
SELECT '' IS NULL;   --> FALSE
```